# What's the best way to automate document comparison in MS Office?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, automation, webserver

I love how, in Microsoft Word, I can go to Tools > Track Changes > Compare Documents, and see a side-by-side annotation of the differences in documents.

Is there a way to automate this from the command line, so that, for example, if a user uploads a document to my server, I can compare the two and return a copy of the annotated diff. (This is for MS Office training purposes.)

I am also looking for similar solutions for Excel and Powerpoint.

I welcome any solution or idea involving scripting/XML diff/etc.